# Compatible Spring dependency for Hibernate 4.3.5.Final

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, orm

I am using Hibernate in my application and now there is a need of upgrading to the latest version of Hibernate(now its 4.3.5.Final) and I have to integrate it with Spring.

Now my question is that which version of Spring is compatible with Hibernate 4.3.5.Final or which latest version of hibernate is compatible with Spring 4.x version.

FYI: During my search I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017466/hibernate-spring-version-compatibility) SO link which tells that how to know the Spring and Hibernate version comparability. And according to that I opened `spring-orm` Maven POM and found that with `spring-orm: 4.0.5.RELEASE` I can use `hibernate-core: 4.2.12.Final` and `hibernate-core: 3.6.10.Final` among these only `hibernate-core: 3.6.10.Final` is working. Then how can I solve this problem of version conflicts.

Comment: This is what we are using currently

`<hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</hibernate.version>
<spring.version>4.0.2.RELEASE</spring.version>`

Comment: @ankur-singhal: That combination is not working. It is giving same exception i.e java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.engine.FilterDefinition