# Determining the correct dependencies of maven?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have got a question about maven dependencies:

if I am looking to implement Hibernate with Spring, is there a way to find out what dependencies do I need exactly with what version number?

It looks like we have same classes in various dependencies and we need to be careful what we include in our pom.xml file.

e.g.

> @Entity

is there in javax.persistence and hibernate-annotations as well, so which one shall I use?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be similar to [Hibernate + spring version compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017466/hibernate-spring-version-compatibility). Generally I would recommend going with the latest versions of Hibernate and Spring.

Other than that, the POM file will list exactly which versions of libraries you will need. If you want a transitive list of all dependencies try the following command on either your project or on the version of hibernate that you choose:

```
mvm dependency:tree
```

Outside of Hibernate and Spring, as long as there are no conflicts with multiple versions of the same jar file, I wouldn't worry about precisely which versions are being used unless you have a specific requirement for your project.

Go ahead and `<exclude>` any conflicting dependencies, but BEWARE doing so may cause unintended behaviors with some libraries.