# Spring 3.2.2 and Hibernate version

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data

Does Spring 3.2.2 work with Hibernate 4.2.17 ? if not, please suggest whats the minimum latest version of spring that does support Hibernate 4.2.17.

regards
aravias

Comment: This was sort of answered earlier (here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017466/hibernate-spring-version-compatibility). You can look at the Hibernate dependencies in the spring-orm.pom - http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm

Answer (score 0):

I believe spring-core will likely work, but spring-orm could hit some issues. Regardless, Spring 3.2.2 is several years old, so I'd recommend moving to up to Spring 4.x if possible.

The maven repo is a nice place to view some of those framework dependencies. [Here's the link for spring-core, specifically](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core).