# compatible spring core with hibernate 5.4

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am using hibernate 5.4.25 and spring 4.3.30 . Getting error as noclassdeffounderror for getFlushMode() . What is spring version to be used with hibernate 5.4.25?

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot?

Comment: Spring 5.2 or up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hibernate + spring version compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18017466/hibernate-spring-version-compatibility)

Comment: i am using spring core not boot

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is that you should use Spring version 5 or greater with Hibernate 5.